# ParallelPython created in thread gives

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-python

Creating a job server gives the error:

```
Python int too large to convert to C long
```

when created in thread (win32), using parallel python version 1.6.5 & Python27.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ParrallelPython.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.job_server = pp.Server(ppservers=self.ppservers, socket_timeout=3600)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pp.py", line 341, in __init__
    self.set_ncpus(ncpus)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pp.py", line 505, in set_ncpus
    range(ncpus - len(self.__workers))])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pp.py", line 138, in __init__
    self.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pp.py", line 150, in start
    self.pid = int(self.t.receive())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pptransport.py", line 148, in receive
    msg = self.r.read(e_size-r_size)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Similar issue to link below:

[ParallelPython Forum Question](http://www.parallelpython.com/component/option,com_smf/Itemid,1/topic,385.0/wap2,wap2)

Comment: Please past sample of how exactly you pull the job server creation

Comment: import pp

class wrapper_class(object):
 ppservers = ()
 job_server = None
 no_of_cpus = None
 
 def __init__():
  self.job_server = pp.Server(ppservers=self.ppservers, socket_timeout=3600))

Comment: its only a basic wrapper.  I use the same method in app and thread.  This is in a windows service.